# calling NSURLConnection on applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, terminate

I'm trying to send `NSURLRequest` via `NSURLConnection` on `applicationWillTerminate` method, The request is called on the client side but its not getting to the my server side.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self sendRandomRequestToServer];
}
```

I guess its because the termination kills the process

Am i right?

If so how can i fix this?

Thanks!

UPDATE -

I know about the 5 seconds that apple gives you so i've experimented -

I tried to run an endless `while` loop on the main thread and its continue to run for 2 minutes on `willTerminate`!!

I also called a method on a background thread using `afterDelay` 0.1 and `dispatchAfter` 0.1 on `willTerminate` - and both didn't get called!

So i don't trust the "5 seconds" rule

Comment: Did you check that `applicationWillTerminate` is actually called?

Comment: Yes i did, NSLog in applicationWillTerminate did it's job.

Comment: The five second rule applies only if you've set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to true, which causes your app to get terminated immediately when the user switches away from it.  Normally, app termination happens only when the system is desperate for resources, so you don't want to block at that point to do any sort of work.  Make your requests when the app moves into the background instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should not run code in the background from `applicationWillTerminate`.

- Once the main thread is cleared the process exits even if background threads are still working.
- `applicationWillTerminate` is the last code block that executes on the main thread. This means that `dispatch_after(time, mainThread)` will not be called.

Comment: Thanks, but this not the answer for me. i've updated my answer.